# std::wofstream operator<< not working as expected

Tags: c++

I'm a Visual Studio 2015 user which was trying to write following function:

```
void saveWordsToFile(const std::string& filename, const std::vector<std::pair<std::wstring, std::wstring>>& words)
{
    std::wofstream fs(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    if (fs.fail()) throw std::runtime_error("loadTextFromFile -> Failed to open '" + filename + "'!");

    for (auto& word : words) fs << word.first << " " << word.second << std::endl;
    fs.close();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::wstring, std::wstring>> words;
    words.push_back({ L"1", L"green" });
    words.push_back({ L"ż", L"yellow" });
    words.push_back({ L"3", L"purple" });
    saveWordsToFile("database.txt", words);
    return 0;
}
```

File **database.txt** was looking like this before program execution:

```
0 test
```

After execution I was expecting:

```
0 test
1 green
ż yellow
3 purple
```

however I got:

```
0 test
1 green
```

It's easy to see that character "ż" is a problem cause, however I need to use it, how to obtain correct output?

Comment: Where is your [MCVE]? Example inputs? Example outputs?

Comment: What do you get if you output `std::distance(words.begin(), words.end())` to the screen?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can I use pastebin to post those examples?

Comment: @Heaven31415 No.  Your question should contain in the body enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Heaven31415: They should be small enough to go verbatim in the question, though _also_ providing a link to a live demo (ideone.com, coliru etc) would be convenient.

Comment: I notice the MCVE page doesn't actually say that...

Comment: @Heaven31415 You also should be using `L" "` to print a wide space, not `" "`.  Also, it isn't a good idea to use non-ASCII string literals within source files.  Use the escape code instead.

Comment: @Heaven31415 I took your code and used Visual Studio 2105.  Immediately I got a warning when I attempted to save the source file concerning characters may not be saved due to encoding differences.  Like I stated, use the escape code instead of the character -- that way you are guaranteed the character you expect when you run the program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for informations. I have managed to save my source file with UTF-8 encoding, used UTF-8 escape sequence for this character, however problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, the stream tries to convert `L'ż'` to a byte stream using [`wcrtomb`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcrtomb), but the conversion fails (due to locale problems, perhaps?).

At that point the stream ends up with `fs.bad()` returning true, and any further output is skipped.